# PRIMARY KEY vs. CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, primary-key

In `postgres`(and many others) we can declare `primary key` in two different ways:

Method 1:

```
create table MyTable(
    MyId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Method 2:

```
create table MyTable(
    MyId SERIAL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_myid PRIMARY KEY (MyId)
)
```

My question is: 
Is there any difference between these declarations (except syntax)? Maybe Hibernate mapping? Or maybe one of these is called a good practice to use?

What I already know - second one is used to set a `PRIMARY KEY` on multiple columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between the two versions is the name for the PK constraint. In the first case Postgres (or the the DBMS in question) will *generate* a name for you. Postgres will create the name `mytable_pkey`. Oracle would choose a name like `SYS_C0029159`

In the second version, *you* have the control over the name.

But there is **no** difference in terms of functionality.

I prefer the second version so that I can control which name is used for the constraint.

Comment: I did not pay attention to the naming problem. Thank you so much. Answer will be accepted ofc.

Comment: @ilovkatie: Keep in mind that the name of the constraint (or rather, the index which is created along with it) must be unique within its schema, so something like `pk_myid` is likely to get you into trouble. It's a good idea to include the name of the table.

Comment: @ilovkatie PostgreSQL's default naming scheme for PKs and constraints is sensible enough that I usually don't override it. I would override the ones Oracle generates, though.